# Svelte - Create Image() object for canvas background from local image

Tags: javascript, svelte

I would like to create a background image pattern for a canvas in my svelte application. I am using the following code to create the pattern but it creates a black canvas.

```
let image = new Image();
image.src = 'images/background.png'
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat'); 
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

The image path is `public/images/background.png`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to wait for the image to load, otherwise there is nothing to draw to the canvas. E.g.

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = 'images/background.png'
image.onload = () => {
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(image, 'repeat'); 
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
};
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/b047e406589a4b51b076dfa5b8d0cb9a?version=3.48.0)